# How do I install gnucap or octave?

Tags: software-center, software-installation, live-usb

I have tried to install gnucap (I downloaded it from the website http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnucap/  with the extension .tar.gz) in the Ubuntu live-usb. I have tried to do it in the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnucap
```

But the problem is that it always tell me :

> E:Unable to Locate Package

Could someone tell me what should I do to install the software?

Answer (score 1):

The way to install a file *.tar.gz is first decompress it with `tar -zxvf file.tar.gz` and then running the binary file or installing with, `./configure; make install`.

Octave is in the Ubuntu universe and can be installed with synaptic or apt-get. The package name is "octave".

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a LiveCD you need to `sudo apt-get update` first, then try your install command.

Try that and then please update your question with the results.

Comment: hey,thanks for your answer,i have installed the program with a *.deb extension file in the software center8not terminal) but there is another problem: in my case the ubuntu system is running in the usb, and everytime you use it, you should intall the octave again, because it will be deleted everytime you shut down the system, the same thing happens with another program that i installed, it there any solution to avoid install the program everytime that i use it?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77714/how-can-i-save-settings-on-live-usb