# Ubuntu 12 Live USB - Boots Fine BUT Is Not Saving Settings Between Sessions

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I save settings on Live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77714/how-can-i-save-settings-on-live-usb)

I moved my Ubuntu Live from CD to USB and the performance is significantly faster. I also expected settings to be saved (changes to the desktop, bookmarks in Firefox, etc...) but that's not happening. What extra step do I need to take to enable saving system and program settings between Live USB sessions?

Thanks